# Loading new iframe into javascript collapse without toggling

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have two links - each should load a different HTML file respectively into an iframe. They will be loaded into the same javascript collapse area. I want each link to load the designated file into the iframe when clicked.

My problem is that IF one html file is loaded into the open (show) collapse area, the collapse area will toggled closed if I click on the second link. I suppose I need an if/then js script but am unsure of the proper logic and syntax?

It should operate logically as expected:
1) If the collapse area is closed (which it is by default), when any link is clicked, it should OPEN and then load in the iframe contents (HTML file)
2) If I click the second link while the collapse is open, it should STAY open (not toggle closed) and simply load in the second iframe contents (HTML file)

What I have below works fine for 'loading' the proper content, but it toggles by default. So if I have the area open with content loaded, it closes if I click the second link.

here are my snippets:

```
<a href="#" onClick='document.getElementById("process_frame").src="html_file_1.php";' data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#content">LINK 1</a>

<a href="#" onClick='document.getElementById("process_frame").src="html_file_2.php";' data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#content">LINK 2</a>

<div id="content" class="collapse">
  <p><iframe id="process_frame" overflow="hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="280" width="100%"></iframe></p>
</div>
```

Any suggestions or samples would be helpful... Thank You

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Do you want the contents of both files to be visible at once if both links are clicked? If you want to change the source, that is a toggle by definition? or do you want the collapse area to have a static height? As you say, what you have works fine ..

Comment: I only want one src to show. the problem is that the COLLAPSE AREA toggles closed when I load in the second source (replacing out the first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to use websites to demo a solution for your question. The snippet doesn't display the results but you can [view a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/e2k6cmLs/) here. A [second solution is here](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/4pn57ms1/1/) (shown in second snippet); it is specific to your two files. You may have to add a path.
These are fairly primitive solutions but as you are only switching between two files, perhaps this may suffice for your needs.

(I set a background colour for the div (not the iframe).. remove this if you wish..)

```js
function togglediv(filename) {
  var frme = document.getElementById("process_frame");

  var file2 = filename;

  if (file2 == " " || filename == undefined) {
    frme.src = "http://www.richmondinnireland.com";
    file2 = frme.src;
  } else {
    frme.src = filename;
    file2 = frme.src;
  }
  //console.log(file2)
  // display frame is hidden 
  if (frme.style.display == 'none') {
    frme.style.display = 'block';
    frme.src = file2;
  }
}
```

```css
#content {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 280px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#process_frame {
  height: 280px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="link1" onClick='togglediv("http://www.hilaryshomeopathy.wordpress.com");' data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#content">LINK 1</a>

<a href="#" id="link2" onClick='togglediv();' data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#content">LINK 2</a>
<br><br>
<div id="content" class="collapse">
  <iframe id="process_frame" overflow="hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="280" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
</script>
```

```css
#process_frame {
  height: 280px;
  overflow: auto;
  width:100%;
}

#file1,
#file2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="file1" onClick='togglediv("1");' data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#content">File 1</a>


<a href="#" id="file2" onClick='togglediv("2");' data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#content">File 2</a>

<div id="content" class="collapse">
  <iframe id="process_frame" overflow="hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" height="280" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
  function togglediv(num) {
    var frme = document.getElementById("process_frame");
    var fileid = num;
    var filename = "html_file_";
    var filetoget = '"' + filename + num + ".php" + '"';
    console.log(filetoget);
    // check if frame is hidden 
    if (frme.style.display == 'none') {
      frme.style.display = 'block';
      frme.src = getfile;
    } /*else {
      //frme.style.display = 'none';
    }*/
  }
  </script>
```